# Ubuntu 15.10 and Epson Artian 837

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and would like to install drivers for my Artisan 837 printer. Using System Settings and Printers, the driver epson-201112W is highlighted for download but the install stalls after entering my password to make changes. The printer is connected to my HP Envy dv7 notebook via USB.

This was also occurring in my previous UBuntu install (14x).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I used Ubuntu Software Centre and searched on Artisan 837. Found Artisan 730 / Artisan 837 Series - Epson Inkjet Printer Driver version epson-inkjet-printer-201112w 1.0.0-1lsb3.2

Installed without plugging the printer in via USB and then followed with Add Printer after plugging it in. Printer installed with a successful Printer test page.